The flutter plugin is not installed in Android Studio
when trying to install the plugin, Android Studio gives this error: Plugin "Flutter" was not installed: We are sorry, but we are currently unable to provide our products or services to you due to export control regulations. 
here is my flutter doctor
enter image description here
After Googling, I thought that flutter was incompatible with JDK 21
I also set the JAVA_HOME variable with the path to JDK 17 version, but it still didn't help

try to install flutter in Android Studio- File- Settings - Plugins - search Flutter and install it after installation done then try to restart Android Studio.

please see that when trying to install the "Flutter" plugin, it failed: Plugin "Flutter" was not installed: We are sorry, but we are currently unable to provide our products or services to you due to export control regulations.

To solve this problem, you need to enable VPN.

Install the plugin manually as follows:
Download the plugin from the website
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter/versions/stable
Go to
Android Studio- File- Settings - Plugins
Then choose the plugin file from the disk
